# REGEX Pattern to deal with or without quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I have the following BBCode that I needed to parse

```
[url=http://www.google.com]Google[/url]
[url="http://www.google.com"]Google[/url]
```

What I am trying to do is extract both **http://www.google.com** and **Google**

Now the difference between the two pieces of BBCode above is the quotes around the url in the second BBCode.

Is it possible for a single regex code to extract my datapoints and account for the presence or abscense of quotes?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:  Just for further clarification.  I am currently using the following Regex pattern:

```
/\[URL=\"?([\s\S]*?)\"?\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/URL\]/gi
```

This will successfully match the URL if it is wrapped in quotes or not.  However, I would like the final result to be stripped of all quotes.  Is this possible via the actual regex pattern itself to simply not include the quotes in the match (if the quotes are even there)

Comment: Yes. Um, what do you want the regex to do? Create an `a` element? Something else? And [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: What you want is possible, but it's more efficient to just strip all quotes ahead of time `s/"//g;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
/\[url=("?)(http://www\.google\.com)\1\](Google)\[\/url\]/
```

will capture `'"'` or `''`; `'http://www.google.com'`; and `'Google'`.

(I realize you don't actually need to capture the `'"'` or `''`, but that's how the regex manages to require that the double-quotes either both be present or both be absent. I also realize that you probably need to cover other link-targets and link-texts besides your example, but I'm assuming that you already know how to handle that, and are just asking about the issue with the optional double-quotes?)

Comment: You are correct I can handle the actual url part, I just need the regex to match the pattern if the url has quotes or does not, but if it does have quotes, it should discard the quotes.  But your pattern will match quotes or no quotes, but if there are quotes, it doesnt actually discard the quotes

Comment: @Mark: I don't know what you mean. The second capture group will not include the quotes. A regex can't actually "discard" things.

Comment: I guess the word "discard" isn't correct, I mean to say 'dont include the quotes in the final match, ***if they are there'.

Comment: @Mark: Well then, this regex *does* discard the quotes: the second capture group is just `'http://www.google.com'`, not `'"http://www.google.com"'`.

Comment: so Im using this final pattern now /\[URL=("?)([\s\S]*?)\1\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/URL\]/gi and it still includes the " in the second capture group.  Maybess its a javascript issue...?

Comment: @Mark: that regex looks broken, in that you have some instances of `[` and `]` that need to be `\[` and `\]`. Also, your subpattern for the URL is so general that it does allow it to include double-quotes; for example, your regex believes that `"asefasef"asefasef"asfasef"` is a valid URL.

Answer (score 2):

To make it more general you would do something like this:

```
/\[url=\"?(https?://[^"\]]+)"?\]([^\[]+)\[\/url\]/
```

which will give you the URL in \1 and the label in \2